# Keras model is stuck at prediction level when running the server with gunicorn

Tags: keras, gunicorn, flask-restplus

I am using keras model to predict something and used flask-restplus to make this as a REST service. so far everything is working fine when I run the server with `python app.py` command.

But I wanted to run this through gunicorn and nginx (`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --error-logfile - -w 4 --access-logfile - --preload wsgi:app -t 900 --preload --reload`), every configuration is correct since It was working fine with the normal endpoint but predict service is not working.

I have investigated and found that my code is stuck at prediction level 
`p = model.predict(np.array(X))`

can some one tell me what could be the issue.

Comment: It has to do with Tensoflow graph and it is fixed

Comment: For the sake of others who find this question, could you provide any detail about what the issue was, and how you fixed it?

Comment: I just had to create a tensor graph and use this for predicting

`import tensorflow as tf`
`graph = tf.get_default_graph()`
`with graph.as_default():
    #predict here`

Answer (score 2):

Running TF2 alpha 0 with Keras, the issue has been the `--preload` flag for me. I suspect the session/graph being the issue. Not an expert though.

Answer (score 0):

For the same problem occurring on more general platforms a solution has been given [here](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/issues/423) - "uninstalling keras and tensorflow and then reinstalling them at the same version" or trying other versions.